# Divisible hull of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Recall that a group is abelian iff it is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.
I know that if $A$ is a torsion-free abelian group, $\Bbb{Q}\otimes A$ is the divisible hull of $A$, up to isomorphism.

Now, suppose $A\subseteq \Bbb{Q}^n$ has rank $n\ge1$ and denote by $\Bbb{Q}\otimes A$ the divisible hull of $A$.
Can I state the equality $\Bbb{Q}\otimes A=\Bbb{Q}^n$?

If $n=1$, then for any $r\in\Bbb{Q}, r\ne 0$, the $\Bbb{Z}$-submodule generated by $r$ equals $\Bbb{Q}$.
In general, whenever $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$ are $\Bbb{Z}$-linearly independent, then $A\supseteq \Bbb{Z}x_1\oplus\dots\oplus\Bbb{Z}x_n$, from which I get $\Bbb{Q}\otimes A\supseteq \Bbb{Q}^n$, the latter one being divisible of rank $n$.

Is it correct or are there some mistakes/imprecisions?
The main point is that I may confuse equality with isomorphism.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes. More generally, if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbf{Q}$ and $A$ is a subgroup (=$\mathbf{Z}$-submodule) of $V$, then the divisible (essential) hull of $A$ can naturally be identified to the $\mathbf{Q}$-subspace $\mathrm{Vect}_\mathbf{Q}(A)$ generated by $A$. This is shown by checking that the latter is an (essential) divisible hull of $A$.